# Need help writing a recursive formula for the following sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, ceiling-and-floor-functions

$$a_n = \lceil n−1/n \rceil$$

Hey Everyone, I am new here made an account because this question has stomped me for a bit, for a normal sequence I have a pretty easy time writing a recursive sequence but this one has completely stomped me if anyone can help guide me with some work and steps it would really help me

Comment: Isn't it just $a_1=0$ and $a_n=n$ for $n>1$?

Comment: That's what I am kinda thinking because for an=n+1/n+1 the answer would be an=n+1 and this problem is similar just without the plus 1 and it's adding

Answer (score 1):

$a_{1} = 0, a_{2} = 2$ and $a_{n+1} = 1+ a_{n}$ for $n > 1$.

Comment: What is $a_2$ ?